# How to get list of custom dimensions in google analytics api v4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking for a method to get the list of custom dimensions in my analytics reports using API v4. In API v3 it was done using management API v3, but I could not found management API v4. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Use the Analytics Management API V3 to [list custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list).

The [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is a stand alone API for querying your analytics data. It is listed in the Developer console as [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/overview).

Analytics Management API in console as [Analytics API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics/overview).

#### Python Example

```
analytics = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

dimensions = analytics.management().customDimensions().list(
  accountId='123456',
  webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
).execute()

DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

analytics.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': '1234',
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dimension1}] # From the mgmt API V3.
    }]
  }
```

### History

In V3 all of Analytics API's (Management, Metadata, Core Reporting, MCF Reporting, Realtime Reporting) were under one top level **Service** called `analytics`. But with the advent of the Analytics Reporting API V4 it was necessary to have a separate/stand-alone API so that you can use both the V3 Management API and the V4 Reporting API in the same application.